# Rails4: How to trigger the callback for attr_accessor while using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, callback, nested-attributes, attr-accessor

Please check the pseudocode:

```
class Team
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
end

class User
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
  attr_accessor :dummy

  before_validation :generate_addresses_attributes
  def generate_addresses_attributes
    # Use the dummy value to set the addresses_attributes
  end
end
```

Now when execute `team.update(users_attributes: [{"0" => { dummy: "changed!" }}])`(the other fields will not change except the dummy attribute), it will not trigger the #generate_addresses_attributes callback since it think there is nothing changes, no save, no callback...

So my question is how to trigger the callback for the virtual attributes, or maybe force save for accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I found that for Rails 5.1+ `attribute` works better than `attr_accessor` for this use case.

`attribute` dirties up the object, thus triggering callbacks when saving it.

```
class User
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
  attribute :dummy, :string

  before_validation :generate_addresses_attributes
  def generate_addresses_attributes
    # Use the dummy value to set the addresses_attributes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found two solution:

1. add callback in Team model to trigger the callback functional manually
2. use the `attribute_will_change!` to override the setter method:

   ```
   class User
     belongs_to :team
     has_many :addresses
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
     attr_accessor :dummy

     def dummy=(value)
       attribute_will_change!("dummy") if @dummy != value
       @dummy = value
     end

     ...
   end
   ```

Comment: you forgot the @ on the if, should read: attribute_will_change!("dummy") if @dummy != value

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some changes to make this work with Rails 5.1.3. If the name of the attr_accessor (`attr_accessor :dummy`) and the setter method (`def dummy=(value)`) are same, there are deprecation warning suggesting to use `attribute :dummy` instead and code did not work as intended. changing the code as follows works:

```
class User
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
  attr_accessor :dummy

  def dummy_attr=(value)
    attribute_will_change!(:dummy)
    self.dummy = value
  end    
  ...
end
```

`:dummy_attr` should be used in strong parameters instead of `:dummy`